# Redirect sitemap.xml

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a multi lingual webpage. the sitemaps are in the directory /share/.

```
share/deutsch.xml
share/englisch.xml
share/french.xml
```

Now how can I redirect in htaccess from the above .xml files to:

```
de/share/deutsch.xml
en/share/englisch.xml
fr/share/french.xml
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you ask for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?[a-z]{2}/share/(\w+)\.xml$ /share/$1.xml [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).